# After changing the project packcage name in my android, App is going to force shutdown. why?

Tags: android, android-studio

Here I changed the project package name, After the changes the project installed successfully on my android phone but unable to process the app, Afer opening the splash screen app is going to force shut down.
please help me to resolve. I have service classes in my project

This is my Logcat

```
2020-10-07 10:41:21.879 15614-15614/com.example.taskreminder E/HW-JPEG-DEC: [HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete](3321): HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
2020-10-07 10:41:21.913 15614-15614/com.example.taskreminder E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.taskreminder, PID: 15614
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.taskreminder/com.example.taskreminder.ui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2793)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6517)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.github.ppartisan.simplealarms.ui.MainFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:630)
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:594)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2309)
        at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:6131)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:389)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:738)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.taskreminder.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6915)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2746)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6517)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.github.ppartisan.simplealarms.ui.MainFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.taskreminder-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.taskreminder-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:616)
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:594) 
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2309) 
        at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98) 
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:6131) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:389) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:738) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.taskreminder.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6915) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2746) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6517) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832) 
2020-10-07 10:41:21.927 15614-15614/com.example.taskreminder I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15614 SIG: 9
```

This is my Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.taskreminder">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ui.splash_screen" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ui.MainActivity">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ui.AddEditAlarmActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.AlarmLandingPageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AlertLandingPageTheme" />

        <service android:name=".service.LoadAlarmsService" />

        <receiver android:name=".service.LoadAlarmsReceiver" />
        <receiver android:name=".service.AlarmReceiver" />
        <receiver
            android:name=".service.BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="${bootPriority}">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Q: What was the old package name?  com.github.ppartisan.simplealarms?  Q: What's the new package name?   Did you do a global "Find" in Android Studio for *ALL* instances of the old name (.java *AND* .xml files), "clean" and "rebuild" everything?

Comment: yes, my old package name is com.github.ppartisan.simplealarms. I replace all files but Q.can you explain how to do a global find?

Comment: this issue is related to the package name change. you have used whole package name with class in some xml or something. Use Ctrl+Shift+F/Cmd+Shift+f to find usage of old package name and replace it with new one.

Comment: Thx I will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't change all of these package name of java code to `com.example.taskreminder.ui`(is it new package name right?). You need to make sure that no old package name by searching keyword `com.github.ppartisan.simplealarms`. you can refer to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/5738042